# Query mongodb with some kind of 'NOT IN' statement

Tags: mongodb

I have the hollowing collection in mongodb:

`+----+----------+-----------------------+
| _id| host     | date                  |
+----+----------+-----------------------+
| 1  | test.com | ISODate('2016-01-01') |
+----+----------+-----------------------+
| 2  | test.com | ISODate('2016-01-03') |
+----+----------+-----------------------+
| 3  | test.com | ISODate('2016-01-04') |
+----+----------+-----------------------+
| 4  | cnn.com  | ISODate('2016-01-05') |
+----+----------+-----------------------+`

I want to bring all the `host`s with `date` greater than 2016-01-03 and not existed before 2016-01-03

So in the case of the table above, my query should return only `cnn.com`.
why? its `date` is greater than 2016-01-03, and it is not appearing bellow  2016-01-03.
I believe that in sql there were `not in` statement involved.

I dont even know how to approche it..

Thanks

Comment: In MongoDB we use documents so we expect to see documents when people ask question not table. That being said what the expected result should look like; array of "hosts" that match your criteria?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve. what do you meant by `date greater than 2016-01-03 and not existed before 2016-01-03 ?`  why third row `test.com` is not valid according to your criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this with aggregation as your best bet in this scenario. Consider the following pipeline operation:

```
var dt = new Date("2016-01-03"),
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$host",
                "date": { "$min": "$date" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": { "date": { "$gt": dt } }
        }
    ];
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

The above pipeline first groups the documents by the host and gets the earliest date from this group. This will then be used in the next pipeline as the filtering basis and in your sample collection you will get the 
following output:

```
{ "_id" : "cnn.com", "date" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to execute a script like this:

```
var date = new Date("2016-01-03")

db.hosts.aggregate([{
  $group: {_id:"$host", date: {$min:"$date"}}},
  {$match: {date: {$gt: date}}},
  {$project:{_id:0, host:"$_id", date:1}}
])
```

and it will output:

```
{ 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "host" : "cnn.com"
}
```